# Strange Behavior of Empty String in JAVA

Tags: java, string

I am working on a Existing code and i found a Strange Behavior while checking a String is null or Empty. The existing code :

```
System.out.println("Length: " + value.length());
if (value != null && value != "") {
   //code
}
```

Output:

```
Length: 0
```

But the if statement becomes true and its executing the code.

When i replaced the if statement with this one:

```
if (value != null && value.length() > 0) {
   //code
}
```

It works perfectly. Any idea why the previous one failed and Why **value != ""** returns true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `equals` method like this:

```
   if (value != null && !"".equals(value)) {
```

Comment: Ok but why value != "" returns true ?

Comment: @st_ahmed because == and != comparing references but not content of string.

Comment: @st_ahmed  Ofcourse  you're right Rustam, and if you want to compare values use equals()

Comment: @Rustam thanks for explaining.

Comment: `value != null` is unnecessary given your use of the Yoda expression.

Answer (score 2):

`String`s are not compared like this:

```
value != ""
```

Use `equals`:

```
!"".equals(value)
```

or `isEmpty`:

```
!value.isEmpty()
```

Because `String` is immutable

Answer (score 1):

When using `==` you are comparing the references which are not equal, that's why the expression evaluates to true.

You can use `StringUtils.isNotEmpty`

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
...
}
```

`true` - if the String is not empty and not null

[Reference](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty(java.lang.String))

Comment: Plus one, that's pretty, and clearer than my Yoda trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare with `value.isEmpty()`. According to the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#663), it will also compare the length.

What you are doing with `!=` is comparing references, not equality.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is an `Object` in java, so you can't use `==` and `!=` with it, because `==` and `!=` comparing references, which is not equal. Use `"".equals(value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
value != ""
```

check for reference equality not the value equality.

if `value` is created like this:

```
String  value=new String("");
```

then there is a high chance that the condition will fail.

For example if you have another String value2

```
String value2=new String("");
```

then

```
  value==value2  // is false.
```

Have a look at this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might have created value variable using new operator:

```
String value = new String();
```

So now if you use following :

```
System.out.println("Length: " + value.length());
if (value != null && value != "") {
     System.out.println("hi")
}
```

It will print hi as value is from heap and literal "" is from string pool  and you are making reference comparison. Use equals method  instead .

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `value != null && !value.isEmpty()`, although you can ace this with the *Yoda Expression*

`"".equals(value)`

which saves you typing out the explicit check for `null`.

You can't use `==` since that would compare the object reference values (which might be different even if the string looks the same), **not** the string contents.